# How can I parse a full HTML document string on the frontend using JS, do DOM transformations, and compile to HTML string (including doctype)?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to create a function to take in a full html document string, run some selectors on it to replace some text/attributes/do other DOM manipulation, and then compile it back to the HTML string (with html, head, body, etc). I've had no success with `$()` or `$.parseHTML()`.

Example

```
function parser(html) {
   var $html= $(html)
   $html('[data-selector="test"]').text('Some Other Text')
   return $html.html()
}

var str = '<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body><div data-selector="test">Some Text</div></body></html>'

expect(parser(str)).toBe(
  '<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body><div data-selector="test">Some Other Text</div></body></html>'
)
```

Note: I rather not use Regexes to do the DOM manipulation

Comment: You can probably do so in an iframe (the only environment where you can control the entire HTML), though I would definitely wonder if there are better ways to accomplish your end goal (though you don't share the real goal and situation so we can't offer other ideas).

Comment: @jfriend00 That's a good idea. Will do some experimenting with the iframe solution. The end goal is to preserve the HTML structure (generated by some 3rd party), but do some dynamic replacing of text and attributes (might want to do anything from insert and image to delete a DOM node + some subnodes

Comment: So, why do you need to process raw html?  Why can't you insert the HTML  into the DOM and then modify the DOM as you need and be done?  Why turn it back into HTML, particularly HTML with `<html><head>` type tags?  Unless you're stuffing that into an iframe, you can't use that directly anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 when the HTML gets inserted into the DOM, it strips away anything outside of the body. We want to preserve everything outside because it is being saved back to the server (and sent as email). The 3rd party sometimes puts <style> and other elements inside the <head>

Comment: Hmm.  You're generating 3rd party HTML on the client that you need to modify and then send to the server?  That's a new one.  I'd be more inclined to move the HTML sanitizing operation server-side.

Comment: @jfriend00 eh it's a pretty obscure use case. The app gets the HTML from a server, then parses it, then builds custom fields based on what is in the HTML, then based on the user's input on the fields, performs modification of the HTML, and allows for a live preview, then compiles the HTML and sends it back to server as string. I think I came up with a solution just testing it out. Will post after

Comment: @jfriend00 figured out a solution after some experimentation. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best I came up with so far. Wrote a small util. I even figured out a way to write the doctype to an iframe.

```js
var parser = {
    // Writes html string to a new iframe
    // Returns the jQuery reference to the iframe
    generateIframe: function (html, operationPromise) {
        var $iframe = $('<iframe>')

        if (operationPromise) {
            operationPromise.always(function () {
                $iframe.remove()
            })
        }

        return this.write($iframe, html)
    },

    // Replaces contents or iframe with new HTML sting
    write: function ($el, html) {
        var iframeDoc = this.getIframeDoc($el)

        iframeDoc.open('text/html', 'replace')
        iframeDoc.write(html)
        iframeDoc.close()

        return $el
    },

    // Reads the contents of an iframe (including top <html> node)
    // Does not include the doctype
    read: function ($el) {
        var iframeDoc = this.getIframeDoc($el)

        var docType = this.doctypeToString(iframeDoc.doctype) || ''

        var html = docType + iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML

        return html
    },

    // Gets the document object from the iframe.
    getIframeDoc: function ($el) {
        var $iframe = $($el) // jQueryify just in case

        var inDom = $iframe.closest('html')

        if (!inDom.length) {
            $iframe
                .css('display', 'none')
                .appendTo('body')
        }

        return $iframe.contents()[0]
    },

    // converts doctype node to string
    doctypeToString: function (node) {
        if (!node) return

        return '<!DOCTYPE ' + node.name
            + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
            + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '')
            + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
            + '>';
    },

    // Gets jQueryified HTML node to do DOM manipulations
    getHtmlNode: function ($el) {
        var iframeDoc = this.getIframeDoc($el)
        return $(iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName('html'))
    }
}


//USAGE

//Promise for end of the operation (optional)
var promise = new $.Deferred()

//Create New Iframe
var $iframe = parser.generateIframe('<html><head><title>Test</title><body><span>Test</span></body></html>', promise)

//Get the HTML node and do horrible unspeakable things to the DOM
var $iHtml = parser.getHtmlNode($iHtml)
$iHtml.find('span').text('Changed').after('<span>Hahah</span>')

//Read the result
var result = parser.read($iframe)

//Complete the operation, killing the iframe
promise.resolve()
```